# Recuperar banco de dados a partir de arquivos .frm e .idb

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Meu backup ficou incompleto e corrompeu meu banco de dados ibdata, agora meu banco não acessa minhas tabelas. Fica dando erro!

Não me importo com os dados! Mas preciso realmente da estrutura das tabelas. Há como recuperar a estrutura a partir desses arquivos que citei?

Se eu clico pra abrir alguma tabela no banco de dados a seguinte mensagem aparece

"Table 'meubanco.nometabela' doesn't exist in engine"

Answer (score 1):

Como dito na pergunta, meu ibdata estava corrompido. No primeiro momento minha reação foi copiar as pastas das tabelas criadas e reinstalar o XAMP. As pastas referentes ao banco de dados criado fica no local `xampp/mysql/data/pastaBancoDeDados`

Após a reinstalação, recoloquei as pastas do banco de dados no local da instalação `mysql/data/pastaBancoDeDados`.

Ao abrir o painel `localhost/phpmyadmin` vi que ao tentar abrir alguma tabela do banco de dados salvo, apresentava o seguinte erro `"Table 'meubanco.nometabela' doesn't exist in engine"`.

Abri então meu banco de dados pelo Heidi e exportei a tabela como SQL. Apaguei a pasta do banco de dados no diretório `mysql/data/pastaBancoDeDados`, logo após fui no painel `localhost/phpmyadmin` e criei um novo banco de dados com o mesmo nome do anterior e importei o sql que o heidiSql gerou.

E funcionou. Recuperei toda estrutura das tabelas com todas as configurações. Só perdi o dados salvo na tabela.

> Essa não é uma resposta definitiva, porém funcionou comigo e pode ser útil pra mais alguém!